# Firebase storage plugin not working on Flutter web

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-web

Based on [this page](https://firebase.flutter.dev) FlutterFire should support Firebase Cloud Storage on web. However, when I init FlutterFire and then run the following code I get an error:

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

...
await store.ref().child(storePath).child(newId).putData(imageData,);
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Task#startPutData on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage)
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:216)
```

This is the setup I have in index.html:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>

<script>
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "sdjsdlksksd", //random strings not actual values
  authDomain: "sdsdkldskldsk",
  databaseURL: "https://askjskdjkd.com",
  projectId: "sdisdkjk",
  storageBucket: "dklsjfkldsfjlkdsjk",
  appId: "1:dghjqwkdwwqo;kewijdkjw",
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
```

And in pubspec.yaml:

```
firebase_storage: ^5.0.1
```

Any idea what might be causing the error? Is it really a bug? Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

try to add core firebase plugin for dart like this :

```
firebase: ^7.3.2
```

now use firebase storage like this :

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;

final storageRef = fb.storage().ref('$folderName/$filname');
```

Comment: if I uploaded file on storage from mobile and wanted to get that on flutter web, how can i do that?

Comment: just use normal `Image.network`

Comment: using that but getting and error instead of image display

Comment: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ImageCodecException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed to load network image.
Another exception was thrown: ImageCodecException: Failed to load network image.
Getting these types of error